# Temporarily redirect PHP error_log destination (STDERR)

Tags: php, unit-testing, stderr, filehandle

I'm running a unit test with PHPUnit on a class that calls `error_log` internally (with message_type 0, so it's the "standard" error output for that PHP environment). When running the test on the command line, the output of `error_log` interrupts the PHPUnit output, because in a command line environment the output of `error_log` is STDERR. Is it possible to capture or redirect the output to STDERR for just one call inside my test code? In pseudocode:

```php
function testSomethingHappens() {

    // TODO redirect STDERR
    $result = (new MyClass())->doSomething();
    // TODO restore STDERR

    $this->assertSame( 'OK', $result );
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about message_type=0 …? https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Comment: @04FS yes, I've edited the question